# Upgrading to Django 1.7: Getting AppRegistryNotReady for translation infrastructure

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-1.7

I'm upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.7 and when I try to do `manage.py runserver` I get the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ben/Code/Repos/myrepo/myproject/core/mail/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from myproject.core.mail.models import IMapEmailMessage, EmailStatus
  File "/home/ben/Code/Repos/myrepo/myproject/core/mail/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from myproject.core.mail.utils import render_templates
  File "/home/ben/Code/Repos/myrepo/myproject/core/mail/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from myproject.core.util import clean_html
  File "/home/ben/Code/Repos/myrepo/myproject/core/util.py", line 1031, in <module>
    def make_url(url, text=_('here')):
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 83, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 325, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 306, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 189, in _fetch
    "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

I haven't used the app registry before, so I assume some setup needs to be done in my apps before translations can be used. The solution I keep seeing is to add this to `wsgi.py`:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

However I already have those lines in there. In the file `myproject/core/util.py` I changed the following line:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

to:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

And that just moved the issue to another file which used `ugettext`. Is it no longer possible to use non-lazy `ugettext`? Or is there some setup I need to do to avoid it being evaluated at import time?

Comment: it's not an answer !! why you don't want to use the last version ? 1.9

Comment: I'm upgrading incrementally to 1.8, but trying to get 1.7 working first.

Comment: I think the last line of the trace is the important one, "Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.", so yes, at import time you need the lazy version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using `make_url(url, text=ugettext('here'))` is that the default argument for `text` is evaluated *when the module is imported*, not when the `make_url` function runs.

You haven't shown the code that generated the second error, so I don't know what was wrong with it.

It is fine to use `ugettext` inside a function (as long as that function doesn't run during import time). For example:

```
def make_url(url, text=None):
    if text is None:
        text = ugettext('here')
```

Note, you can still do `import uggettext as _` in your code, I've just used `ugettext` above to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I just needed to change `ugettext` to `ugettext_lazy` wherever I got that error. Luckily there were only 2 cases; mostly `ugettext` worked as before.